# Comparing two strings in C?

Tags: c, string, comparison

This code is not working as the comparison is not being done. Why?

All names get past the `if`.

```
printf("Enter Product: \n");
scanf("%s", &nameIt2);
printf("Enter Description: \n");
scanf("%s", &descriptionI);
printf("Enter Quantity: \n");
scanf("%d", &qtyI);
printf("Enter Order Quantity: \n");
scanf("%s", &ordqtyI);

while (fscanf(fp4, "%s %s %d %s\n", &namet2, &description2, &qty2, &ordqty2) != EOF){
    if(namet2 != nameIt2)
        fprintf(fpt2, "%s %s %d %s\n", &namet2, &description2, qty2, &ordqty2);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &variable` looks fishy. The array name "decays" into a pointer to the first element, so the & is either unnecessary or a severe bug, depending on the variable types.

Answer (score 72):

To compare two C strings (`char *`), use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). The function returns `0` when the strings are equal, so you would need to use this in your code:

```
if (strcmp(namet2, nameIt2) != 0)
```

If you (wrongly) use

```
if (namet2 != nameIt2)
```

you are comparing the pointers (addresses) of both strings, which are unequal when you have two different pointers (which is always the case in your situation).

Answer (score 15):

For comparing 2 strings, either use the built in function `strcmp()` using header file `string.h`

```
if(strcmp(a,b)==0)
    printf("Entered strings are equal");
else
    printf("Entered strings are not equal");
```

OR you can write your own function like this:

```
int string_compare(char str1[], char str2[])
{
    int ctr=0;

    while(str1[ctr]==str2[ctr])
    {
        if(str1[ctr]=='\0'||str2[ctr]=='\0')
            break;
        ctr++;
    }
    if(str1[ctr]=='\0' && str2[ctr]=='\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are currently comparing the addresses of the two strings.

Use [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare the values of two char arrays

```
 if (strcmp(namet2, nameIt2) != 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You try and compare pointers here, not the contents of what is pointed to (ie, your characters).

You must use either `memcmp` or `str{,n}cmp` to compare the contents.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `strcmp`:

```
strcmp(namet2, nameIt2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the array indicates the starting address. Starting address of both `namet2` and `nameIt2` are different. So the equal to (`==`) operator checks whether the addresses are the same or not. For comparing two strings,  a better way is to use `strcmp()`, or we can compare character by character using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the WHY in your question:

Because the equality operator can only be applied to simple variable types, such as `float`s, `int`s, or `char`s, and **not** to more sophisticated types, such as **structures or arrays**.
To determine if two strings are equal, you must explicitly compare the two character strings character by character.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strcmp(sr1,str2)) // this returns 0 if strings r equal 
    flag=0;
else flag=1; // then last check the variable flag value and print the message 

                         OR

char str1[20],str2[20];
printf("enter first str > ");
gets(str1);
printf("enter second str > ");
gets(str2);

for(int i=0;str1[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    if(str[i]==str2[i])
         flag=0;
    else {flag=1; break;}
}

 //check the value of flag if it is 0 then strings r equal simple :)
```