# How to check if the name user inputted in InsertList() does not equal one that is already in the array waitlist?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to ask the user to input another name, if the name is already in the array list. How do I do that?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 12
#define MAX_LENGTH 25

char waitList[MAX_SIZE][MAX_LENGTH];
char numberInParty[MAX_SIZE];
int count = 0;

void insertList() {
  char name[MAX_LENGTH];
  int number, i;
  printf("Name? ");
  scanf("%s", name);
  printf("Number of people in party? ");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  strcpy(waitList[count], name); 
  numberInParty[count] = number;
  printf("Inserted\n\n");
  count++;
```

Comment: Use strcmp function of <string.h>

Comment: I think its a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232990/comparing-two-strings-in-c/14233037

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate over the array and check if each element in it - is `name` the user just entered.

Therefore, you need to know the size of the array. There is no function for checking the length of an array in C. However, if the array is declared in the same scope as where you want to check, you can do the following

```
int len = sizeof(waitList)/sizeof(waitList[0]);
```

Then, use a `for` loop and `strcmp`:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < len ; i++ ) {
    if ( strcmp(waitList[i], name) == 0 ) {
        printf("Name already exists. Please enter another ");
        scanf("%s", name);
    }
}
```

You can read more about `strcmp` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm).